# Call function as component React-Native

Tags: react-native, drawer, navigator

I want to use state to manipulate DrawerNavigator params, and set it on componentWillMount().

The problem here is: how to call function as component in react-native?

The render method is what should be updated:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      param0: "",
      param1: ""
    };
    this.Drawer = this.Drawer.bind(this);
  }

  Drawer() {
    return createDrawerNavigator({
      Screen0: {
        screen: Screen2Module,
        params: {
          screenTitle: this.state.param0,
        },
      },
      Screen1: {
        screen: Screen1Module,
        params: {
          screenTitle: this.state.param1,
        },
      } 
    });
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    Locales((locales) => this.setState({
      param0: locales.param0,
      param1: locales.param1
    }));
  }

  static router = () => this.Drawer().router;
  static navigationOptions = () => this.Drawer().navigationOptions;


  render() {
    return <Drawer navigation={this.props.navigation} />;
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: this is very... very confusing... why don't you call `createNavigation` in `render`? that would make a lot more sense for what you want to do

Comment: also `componentWillMount` is deprecated. use `componentDidMount` or constructor logic to initialize things